# Variable be assign or refresh Unicode characters garbled (ODI)

Tags: character-encoding, oracle-data-integrator

I have using Variables refresh text from MSSQL, but the return garbled characters that contains Chinese characters.

Running the same script in MSSQL returns the correct result without garbled.

Do you have the same issues , and how to fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you share sql refresh variable?
I think you should remove special character when you select to refresh variable?
Something like this(on Oracle):

```
select 
REGEXP_REPLACE('漢字123 vietnamdataengineer@gmail.com 漢字','[^a-z_A-Z0-9 ]') as STR 
from dual;
```